# Import Error appearing in command line (using sublime text editor)

Tags: python

I have this code in two different python modules and both the files are saved to the desktop

mymodule.py

```
def func():
  print("Hi")
```

myprogram.py

```
from mymodule import func
func()
```

> Import Error: cannot import name func from mymodule

Comment: Please [edit] to describe how you are running this program. Are these 2 files in the same folder? What exactly do you enter on the command line? From where are you running it?

Answer (score 0):

first of all make sure that your mymodule.py file and app.py or whatever it is are in the same folder,
if you can not move them to same folder do this :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/<<path of your mymodule.py file>>/')
```

and then:

```
from mymodule import func
func()
```